# How to check the number of columns for each row in a csv file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a big file with tens of thousands of lines containing data separated by `|` for bulk insert in my database.
I know there should be say 10 columns.

Because some of the data may accidentally contains the delimiter `|`, errors can occur because the number of columns will not match for this line.

I'm trying to count the number of lines that have more than 20 columns to check that the file is valid :

```
@ECHO OFF
set /a count=0
FOR /f "tokens=10,* delims=|" %%i in (%1) DO (
  if not "%%j"=="" (
    set /a count+=1
  )
)
echo %count%
:eof
```

It works well ... but only if not any field is empty, in which case the count is shifted because `delims` handles delimiters like whitespaces

```
e.g  
    1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10 => cool, 10 columns
    1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|almost got|you|10 => found 11 columns 
    1|2|3|4||6|7|8|got|you|10 => damn, reports as 10 columns
```

How can I solve this using only the command line/Windows batch ?

**N.B.** I can't modify the file to enclose data in quotes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findstr` and give it a regex.  So let's say you know your line has at least 10 columns, which means it has at least 9 pipe characters.  And you want to find which lines have 10 or more pipe characters.  We can come up with this regex:

```
.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*  Line has at least 10 pipe characters, meaning
                                  some data field contains a pipe character.
```

Give that regex to `findstr`.

```
findstr /R ".*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*" data.txt
```

This prints all malformed lines.  Give the output of that to `find /c` to count the number of lines it spits out.

```
findstr /R ".*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*" data.txt | find /c "|"
```

Example `data.txt`:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10                 good - 10 columns
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|almost got|you|10    bad  - 11 columns
1|2|3|4||6|7|8|got|you|10            bad  - 11 columns
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9||                  bad  - 11 columns
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9                    good - 10 columns
1|2|3|4|5|6|7                        gotcha - less than 10 columns not detected
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|                   good - 10 columns
|||||||||                            good - 10 columns
||||||||||                           bad  - 11 columns

C:\>findstr /R "^.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*$" data.txt
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|almost got|you|10    bad  - 11 columns
1|2|3|4||6|7|8|got|you|10            bad  - 11 columns
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9||                  bad  - 11 columns
||||||||||                           bad  - 11 columns

C:\>findstr /R "^.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*$" data.txt | find /c "|"
4
```

Comment: Great, didn't even know findstr existed